# Can I use other directory beside /home?

Tags: permissions, directory, home

I'm out of space for my /home partition. I would like to use other directory to store some big files and videos. Is there directory that I can use?
I think of /usr/myowndir or /mnt/myowndir.
But I don't have permission to write in /usr or /mnt dir.

Is there a way to make new directory in /usr or /mnt then set the permission to writeable by non sudo user?

Comment: extend `/home` partition and filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be `root` to make a subdirectory of `/usr` and root can also set the ownership/permissions of any directory there (or anywhere else) to something that will allow you to use it as your normal user.

Comment: After I try create folder /mnt/storage, I change permission using sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/storage (but still not writeable). Then I change ower using chown and it work.